# Idiomatic way of converting multiple Options into list

Tags: scala

I quite often encounter a problem of converting mostly optional settings-like object into strings or lists (e.g. into arguments for launching some external program). Usually I end up with imperative code similar to this:

```
case class Options(host: Option[String], user: Option[String], password: Option[String]) {
  def argsString = {
    val args = new ArrayBuffer[String]()

    if (host.nonEmpty) {
      args+="--host"
      args+=host.get
    }

    if (user.nonEmpty) {
      args+="--user"
      args+=user.get
    }

    if(password.nonEmpty) {
      args+="--password"
      args+=password.get
    }

    args mkString " "
  }
}
```

Is there a more FP-like way of doing this?

Answer (score 5):

There are a few ways. This should work:

```
case class Options(host: Option[String], user: Option[String], password: Option[String]) {
  def argsString: String = { 
    host.map("--host " + _) ++ 
    user.map("--user " + _) ++ 
    password.map("--password " + _) 
  }.mkString(" ")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another possibility, based on a list of (argument name, argument value) tuples filtered (`collect`) with pattern matching:

```
case class Options(host: Option[String], user: Option[String], password: Option[String]) {

  def argsString(): String =
    Seq(("host", host), ("user", user), ("password", password))
      .collect { case (arg, Some(value)) => s"--$arg $value" }
      .mkString(" ")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `Scala 2.13` we can generalize the concept to any case class whose fields are `Option[String]`s:

```
case class Options(host: Option[String], user: Option[String], password: Option[String]) {

  def argsString(): String =
    (productElementNames zip productIterator)
      .collect { case (arg, Some(value)) => s"--$arg $value" }
      .mkString(" ")
}
```

---

This is due to the fact that with `Scala 2.13`, we can retrieve the field names of a case class with [`productElementNames`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/Product.html#productElementNames:Iterator[String]):

```
Options(Some("localhost"), None, Some("abcd")).productElementNames.toList
// List("host", "user", "password")
```

Zipped with case class field values thanks to [`productIterator`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/Product.html#productIterator:Iterator[Any]), this gives us an iterator of argument names and values:

```
Options(Some("localhost"), None, Some("abcd")).productIterator.toList
// List(Some(localhost), None, Some(abcd))

(productElementNames zip productIterator).toList
// List((host, Some("localhost")), (user, None), (password, Some("abcd")))
```

Based on this we can then pattern match to filter out `None`s and make a String out of the filtered parameters to get:

```
--host localhost --password abcd
```

Answer (score 0):

```
case class Options(host: Option[String], user: Option[String], password: Option[String]) {
  def argsString: String = {
     Seq(
       host.map("--host " + _),
       user.map("--user " + _),
       password.map("--password " + _)
     )
     .flatten
     .mkString(" ")

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it with something like:

```
case class Options(host: Option[String], user: Option[String], password: Option[String]) {
  def args: Seq[String] =
    host.toList.flatMap(h => List("--host", h)) ++
    user.toList.flatMap(u => List("--user", u)) ++
    password.toList.flatMap(p => List("--password", p))

  def argsString: String = args.mkString(" ")
}
```

I tend to prefer moving built-up strings to the outermost edge possible, as that means that if some other layer wants to manipulate the args, it doesn't have to split (or worse parse) a built-up string.

Answer (score 0):

```
def argsString0 =
    Array(s"${host.fold("")(e => s"--host ${e}")}",
          s"${user.fold("")(e => s"--user ${e}")}",
          s"${password.fold("")(e => s"--password ${e}")}").mkString(" ")
```

Answer (score -2):

How about this?

```
case class Options(host: Option[String], user: Option[String], password: Option[String]) {
  def argsString =
    List(
      host.map(List("--host", _)),
      user.map(List("--user", _)),
      password.map(List("--password", _))
    ).flatten.flatten.mkString(" ")
}
```

Comment: Not the downvoter but i assume because you've unnecessarily put used `List` when mapping over `Option`s

Comment: @randbw Why do you think it is unnecessary? This design creates a list of arguments and then adds the separators afterwards in a single place. Other solutions add the separator in different places in the code which I consider less elegant. I suspect I was actually downvoted to promote another answer (given that I was the first to answer).